# Can a result be "open"?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm not a native speaker. Is it good English to say

> the result is (still) *open*

meaning that for whatever reason the result (e.g., of a study, of an examination) is not available yet, but will be in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that situation, I would go with [*pending*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pending):

> 1. awaiting a conclusion or a confirmation
> 2. begun but not completed

So,

> the results are (still) pending

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase makes sense but would feel incomplete to most English speakers because  *open*'s placement in this phrase, while meaning *not finally settled*, could also mean *welcoming discussion, criticism, and inquiry* and would then be followed by *to* or *for*, e.g., *open to interpretation* or @pageman's *open for speculation*.

(italicized definitions from *[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1273535?rskey=ODtK1o&result=1#m_en_us1273535)*)

Answer (score 0):

or you can use the idiom ["up in the air"](http://www.learnenglishfeelgood.com/americanidioms/lefgidioms_u.html)

> The results of the examinations are
>   still **up in the air**.

if you really want to use something with "open" you can try:

> The results of the examinations are
>   still **open for speculation**.

Comment: These sound too informal to me... Are they?

Comment: @Alenanno you would use "open for speculation" informally? hmmm plus I did QUALIFY my first example as idiomatic